# Is there a way to start a node application with pm2 running as root?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, pm2

I have a node express app used as GUI for an embedded raspberry pi controller that manipulates a device via the gpio interface.  The app runs fine with the command "sudo node app.js", but fails if I try to run it with the command "node app.js" with the error...

```
2022-08-28 21:48:03 initCheckPermitted: 
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Sorry, you don't have permission to run this program.    |
|Try running as root, e.g. precede the command with sudo. |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
/home/ko2f/resonate/node_modules/pigpio/pigpio.js:17
    pigpio.gpioInitialise();
```

I would like to use pm2 to automatically run my app each time the controller restarts.

Is there a way to start a node application with pm2 running as root?

---

resonate is the actual name of my app.

from my node application folder, I entered the command:

```
sudo pm2 start resonate.js
```

and got a [pm2] Process successfully started response.  I entered the command:

```
sudo pm2 status
```

and pm2 returned a status of 'errored'.  What did I miss?

Comment: Just run pm2 with sudo. It will create config, startup scripts etc. belonging to root user.

Answer (score 1):

Like your messages says.

Try using `sudo` before your command

`sudo pm2 start server.js`